# Why can't use data after post (React JS)

Tags: javascript, axios

i'm post data to nav and get it after post i use

```
.then(data => console.log(data.PathPDF))
.then(data => window.open(data.PathPDF, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer'));
```

in the first line i can get value in console but in window.open get error "Cannot read property 'PathPDF' of undefined"

Comment: Calling `console.log` will always return undefined. This would then be passed to the next `then` meaning that `data` in the second `then` would be undefined. Try using `console.log(data.PathPDF) || data`, or `console.log(data.PathPDF), data` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.then(data => console.log(data.PathPDF))
```

Whatever value you return from your `.then` callback becomes the value in the resulting promise. `console.log` returns `undefined`, and so that's the value your second `.then` gets passed in.

Either change this to re-return the `data`:

```
.then(data => {
  console.log(data.PathPDF)
  return data;
})
.then(data => window.open(data.PathPDF, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer'));
```

Or just have a single `.then`:

```
.then(data => {
  console.log(data.PathPDF);
  return window.open(data.PathPDF, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer');
})
```